# Openshift redirects wp-admin to https

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, openshift

In general option in wordpress, I have changed the wordpress directory to be on `http://mywebsite.com` but wordpress dashboard is still in htpps causing mixed content warning and images in dashboard are not displayed even after disabling mixed content filter on firefox.

I this is my `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

What is the possible solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: Change your WP permalink settings also to have URLs as `http://`

Comment: Its already set to http:// not https:// but dashboard is still in https://

Comment: Use a new browser to test.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a setting in your wp-config.php file that directs all admin traffic over https.  You would need to disable that option for your admin panel to work correctly.

`FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` needs to be false:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

solves the issue. See relevant WordPress Codex pages:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/force_ssl_admin

Comment: Thanks for the information.
 In wp-config.php FORCE_SSL_ADMIN was set to true
`define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);` and now I changed the value to false. Problem solved. Dashboard is http now. Please update the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: 2 hours of banging my head. This fixed!

Comment: is there any other fix for this issue? for example if I don't want to leave https for admin page for security reasons maybe...

Comment: What other fix would you want there to be? Either you do want SSL (set it to true) or you don't want SSL (set it to false).