# SSL error while opening WordPress Admin

Tags: ssl, openshift

I am having a domain [chansek.com](http://www.chansek.com), hosted in Openshift through a Wordpress application. But the problem is, when I am trying to open my Wordpress Admin, it's always trying to connect through **https** instead of **http**. As I don't have any SSL certificate, it gives me some warning message. Please see the below screenshot for better understanding.

How do I make it go through **http**? I don't want any SSL certificate for my website as it's a personal blog.

[image: ScreenShot]

I am also trying to use JetPack plugin. But it gives following error.

```
Your website needs to be publicly accessible to use Jetpack: site_inaccessible Error
Details: The Jetpack server was unable to communicate with your site 
https://www.chansek.com [IXR -32300: transport error: http_request_failed SSL: 
no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.chansek.com']
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options:
1.) Disable using SSL for the admin in your wp-config.php file. ([Openshift redirects wp-admin to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685369/openshift-redirects-wp-admin-to-https/22686369#22686369))
2.) Upgrade to the bronze plan and the purchase a custom ssl certificate and install it

You are getting that error from jetpack because the ssl certificate is not valid for your custom domain, only for your app-domain.rhcloud.com address.

Comment: For reference here the WP Codex offers more insight to the Admin over SSL configuration - https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL